# Rotina com o CakePHP está lenda para exibir dados na view

Tags: cakephp, view

Estou usando o CakePHP 2.4.2.

Não estou conseguindo entender a lentidão para exibir os dados. Na medida que aumenta o número de registros na tabela, mais lento vai ficando.

A estrutura da tabela é id (int(11)), nome (varchar(255)), status (char(1)). Os registro são pequenos.

A tabela tem cerca de 2500 registros e passa de um minuto e meio o tempo de resposta para que todos os sejam retornados, sendo que há uma paginação de 10 registros por página. Para conseguir trabalhar eu tenho limitar o retorno de no máximo 250 registros.

Sou novo no CakePHP e estou tentando dar manutenção numa rotina que peguei pronta.

```
class ProcessosController extends AppController {
    public $name = 'Processos';
    public function beforeFilter() {
    parent::beforeFilter();
    $this->Security->unlockedActions = array('excluir','delete','salvar');
    }
    function index(){
    $processos = $this->Processo->find('all',
         array(
                'conditions' => array('Processo.status' => 1),
                'order' => array('Processo.nome ASC')
            )
        );
        $this->set('processos', $processos);
        $this->set('_serialize', array('processos'));
    }
?>
```

Comment: Já tentou fazer um select diretamente no prompt do mysql  )?

Comment: É altamente recomendavel o uso de índices também.

Answer (score 0):

Esse model tem relacionamento com outros models? Se tiver, coloque o recursive = -1, dessa forma:

```
function index(){
    $processos = $this->Processo->find('all', array(
        'conditions' => array('Processo.status' => 1),
        'order' => array('Processo.nome ASC'),
        'recursive' => -1,
    ));
    $this->set('processos', $processos);
    $this->set('_serialize', array('processos'));
}
```